# SVn help ignoring a folder: 'Explicit target required'

Tags: svn, terminal

I am trying to get SVN to ignore a folder by typing:

```
svn --username myusername propset svn:ignore MyFolder/mysubFolder
```

However, I am getting the following error message:

```
svn: Explicit target required ('MyFolder/mysubFolder' interpreted as prop value)
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to specify the directory where to apply the setting, which is most likely the current directory (`.`):

```
svn --username myusername propset svn:ignore MyFolder/mysubFolder .
```

Answer (score 5):

**svn --username yourusername propset svn:ignore params1 params2**

params1 is what you want to ignore, and params2 is the parent folder of what you want to ignore. In summary, you need supply both params.

For example:
If you want to ignore all files in gen folder, like this:
svn propset svn:ignore "*" ./gen

If you want to ignore folder named gen, like this:
svn propset svn:ignore 'gen' ./
or
svn propset svn:ignore 'gen' .